# Insert a space between numbers and letters in column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert a space between numbers and letters in a column.

Example of the text in the column.

925 LANE AVE SOUTH apt106H
85SW162ND
P O BOX101586
11939 magnolia falls DRIVE
1029BAILLIES ROAD
6870 SR207
14701 nw 77 TH AVENUE
14701NW77THAVENUE
1325NW93CTB103
Po Box272771
2137FERNWOODlane
5702 highway 17/92 CASSELBERRY FL
2254 NW 82 NS AVE
9110SW13TH aveAPT #203

I was thinking of a flag which will toggle if it finds a non-numeric character and will also add a space in the process. This should also work when it finds a numeric character.

```
Function AddSpace(Str As String) As String
Dim StringLength As Integer
Dim Flag As Integer ' Flag 0 means char, 1 means numeric
StringLength = Len(CellRef)
For i = 1 To StringLength
If IsNumeric(Mid(CellRef, i, 1))
Then Flag = 1 
Result = Result & Mid(CellRef, i, 1)
else Flag = 0   
endif

Result = Result & Mid(CellRef, i, 1)
Next i
AddSpace = Result
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, edit your question and copy the code there. We cannot understand it from a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Public Function spacer(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, buf As String, L As Long
    L = Len(s)
    If L < 2 Then
        spacer = s
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    buf = Left(s, 1)
    For i = 2 To L
        v1 = Right(buf, 1)
        v2 = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If (v1 Like "[a-zA-Z]" And v2 Like "[0-9]") Or (v2 Like "[a-zA-Z]" And v1 Like "[0-9]") Then
            buf = buf & " "
        End If
        buf = buf & v2
    Next i
    
    spacer = buf
End Function
```

[image]